# chutzpah not importing referenced file in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I have a simple test file "test.js"

```
/// <reference path="./api.js" />

describe("value is true", function () {
    var api = new Api();

    describe("audio", function () {
        it("returns white space when text is null", function () {
            expect(api.value).toEqual(true);
        });            
    });        
});
```

and the file that implements the class "api.js" under the same directory

```
var Api = function () {
    this.value = true;
};
```

I got the test runner from nuget (version 4.2.4) installed one level up in the directory structure.

I execute the following command

```
 .\chutzpah.console.exe .\Tests\test.js
```

The result is "Test 'value is true:encountered a declaration exception' failed ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Api in file:///C:/temp/tools/Tests/
test.js (line 4)"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate and it worked fine. Are you sure the files are in the same directory. Here is my setup:

[image]

And the files are exactly what you copied and then I ran the following and it passed:

[image]

Comment: A brand new test probed that I was doing something wrong, not sure what